# Using Environment Variables to Configure a Sails.js app for CircleCI

Tags: environment-variables, sails.js

I've accessed environmental varibales with node apps before with `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`, but I was curious to try [Sails' alternative solution](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/configuration). It seems like I should be able to put in a dummy value (or nothing) in the `/config/foo.js` file, then overwrite it with a carefully named environmental variable. I modeled my setup on [this example](https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/92769de1e6c10f0159f97d575e18c6cf).

Unfortunately, CircleCI seems to be ignoring the environmental variable and using the dummy value instead. Have I set something up incorrectly? FYI, I'm using `/config/local.js` (no environment variables) to overwrite the password on my local machine and everything works fine...

**/config/datastores.js:**

```
module.exports.datastores = {
    postgresqlTestDb: {
      adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
      host: 'test-postgres.myhost.com',
      user: 'postgres',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
      database: 'my-db',
    },
};
```

**Environment Variables in CircleCI:**

```
sails_datastores__postgresqlTestDb__password = theRealPassword
```

**Error in CircleCI:**

```
1) "before all" hook:
   Error: done() invoked with non-Error: {"error":{"name":"error","length":104,"severity":"FATAL","code":"28P01","file":"auth.c","line":"307","routine":"auth_failed"},"meta":{"adapter":"sails-postgresql","host":"test-postgres.myhost.com","user":"postgres","password":"PASSWORD","database":"","identity":"postgresqlTestDb","url":"postgres://postgres:PASSWORD@test-postgres.myhost.com:5432/my-db"}}
    at sails.lift (test/lifecycle.test.js:46:23)
...
```

**The Important part of the error:**

```
"url":"postgres://postgres:PASSWORD@test-postgres.myhost.com:5432/my-db"
```

I want to connect to `postgres://postgres:theRealPassword@test-postgres.myhost.com:5432/my-db` instead...

Answer (score 0):

I just set an ENV variable for the entire connection URL. looks something like this:

`sails_datastores__default__url: postgresql://user:passwrod@host:port/databse`

I think in your example you are missing the "default" part